# Does "Service Provider" dimension correspond to "ISP Organization" filter in Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to create a filter based on "Service Provider" dimension (Audience > Technology > Network), but there is no such filter field, only "ISP Organization" (and there is no such dimension in return). Do those two mean the same?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, ISP stands for Internet Service Provider - they are the same :) x